# Cannot read property options on undefined with React and react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have the following code trying to use i18next in a react project that I want to translate.

But when calling the app I get an error that in the I18n component a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined` occurs.

```
// i18n components
import i18n from "/modules/ui/i18n";s
import { I18n } from 'react-i18next';
console.log(i18n);
export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <I18n>
    {
      (t, { i18n }) => (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      )
    }
  </I18n>
);
```

I have added the log statement and it returns an clearly defined `i18n` object with an `options` property. Not sure what to do.

I've moved the  property into the specific component in case it was not compatible with the router function and the same issue has occurred.

**Update**

The issue was in the i18n component.

```
i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(Backend)
  .init({ ... })
```

Was changed to

```
i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(Backend)
  .use(reactI18nextModule)
  .init({ ... })
```

and the issue was solved.

Comment: Can you change to this (t, { i18n, t, ready })?

Comment: i'm facing this issue at my end. can you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the answer in the update I was missing the `.use(reactI18NextModule)` section.

Comment: Would like to point out that this has changed to `.use(initReactI18next)` in later versions.